# как получить нестатический обьект в статическом методе?

Tags: c#, unity3d

есть два скрипта, в первом вызывается статический метод из второго скрипта, в этом методе нужно получить нестатический обьект. Знаю,что нестатик методы не имеют доступа к статикам, пробовал создать экземпляр, но все равно не получается(( сделать объект статическим не могу,он нужен в инспекторе. подскажите как выйти из ситуации?
скрипт 1:

```
public class Z2placeComplete : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static bool isZ2Complete;
    public static Vector3 z2CompleteOffset = new Vector3(0.18f, 0.54f, 0);

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        changeBrick.test(z2CompleteOffset, isZ2Complete);
    }
}
```

скрипт 2 (нет доступа к обьекту palka  из-за его нестатичности):

```
public class changeBrick : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject palka;

    public static void test(Vector3 completeOffset, bool isComplete)
    {
        if (isComplete)
        {
            changeBr(palka, completeOffset);
        }
    }
}
```

пробовал создать экземпляр класса внутри статик метода, в коде ошибок нет,но при запуске метода выдает ошибку " не задана ссылка на обьект" :

```
public static void test(Vector3 completeOffset, bool isComplete)
{
    if (isComplete)
    {
        changeBrick changeBrick = new changeBrick();
        changeBr(changeBrick.palka, completeOffset);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

можно передать нестатический объект в качестве параметра для статического метода

```
    public static void test(changeBrick nonStaticObject, Vector3 completeOffset, bool isComplete)
    {
        if (isComplete)
        {
            changeBr(nonStaticObject.palka, completeOffset);
        }
    }
```

если changeBr нестатический метод, его тоже следует вызывать у объекта

```
    public static void test(changeBrick nonStaticObject, Vector3 completeOffset, bool isComplete)
    {
        if (isComplete)
        {
            nonStaticObject.changeBr(nonStaticObject.palka, completeOffset);
        }
    }
```

если нет объекта, который надо передать в параметры test(), ищешь его на сцене через GameObject.Find("имя объекта на сцене")

Comment: я не могу передать нестатический обьект в качестве параметра,так как метод вызывается из другого скрипта, и из него нет доступа к нестатик обьекту(  А changeBr статический метод,с ним все норм.

Comment: по другому ни как, либо ищешь объект на сцене через GameObject.Find("имя объекта на сцене"), либо хранишь объект в том скрипте, в котором вызываешь метод, либо хранишь обект статически (но тогда доступа к нему из инспектора у тебя не будет)

Comment: ок, но только тогда я не понимаю,почему, если я внутри метода test создаю экземпляр класса, и у него беру ссылку на обьект palka, то и Rider  мне говорит о том,что это тот самый обьект, и ошибок нет, но когда метод стартует, unity говорит что не задана ссылка на обьект?

Comment: ты создал не экземпляр класса gameObject, а экземпляр класса MonoBehaviour

Comment: @артембузинов, статический метод принадлежит типу, в вашем случае Z2placeComplete , и на этом типе можно вызывать статические члены. Не статические члены принадлежат конкретному объекту. Когда вы создаете объект, используя оператор new - происходит выделение памяти в куче, и помещения НОВОГО объекта в это место, а вам передается ссылка на объект. Но это - новый объект, не тот, в котором вы работали. Все его ссылочные члены, как правило, не инициализированы (= null, если в конструкторе не заданы). Прочтите про ссылочные и значимые типы, кучу и стек, оператор new, члены класса и типа.